# Delete vertices one by one, when using the 'Add Mesh: Extra Objects' addon to plot points

Tags: python, scripting, objects, add-on, vertices

I am using the 'Add Mesh: Extra Objects' addon in Blender to plot points at specified coordinates. Each point is added to a mesh of points instead of being a separate object. My goal is to implement a functionality where I can delete individual points from the mesh one by one, similar to a stack.

Current Approach:
I have an operator with an execute method that plots points at specified coordinates using primitive_vert_add(). Each point's coordinates are stored in a list named points_list.

Challenge:
Now, I need a method to delete vertices one by one from the mesh created using the addon.

Requirements:

1. Delete vertices individually from the mesh.
2. Ensure that deletion occurs in a stack-like manner, meaning the most recently added point can be deleted first.

Comment: Hello, I feel like the two paragraphs of your post ask a different question, could you be a bit more specific about your problem ? Cheers

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope its more specific, thanks